# how to test ngrx/effects class in angular2?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, ngrx-effects

i have a ngrx/effects class below. I want to test it but when I run my test, it is not printing anything but still passes. the test should be when I trigger an action TRIGGER_LOAD_NAVIGATION_ITEMS, I should get mocked resultset and returned action type as LOAD_NAVIGATIONS_LINKS

**EFFECTS file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Effect, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { NavigationActionType } from 'app/core/store/actions/navigation/navigation.action';
import { NavigationService } from 'app/core/services/navigation.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationServiceEffect {
    @Effect()
    navigations$ = this.actions$
                        .ofType(NavigationActionType.TRIGGER_LOAD_NAVIGATION_ITEMS)
                        .switchMap( () => this.navigationService.load())
                        .map(data => ({ type: NavigationActionType.LOAD_NAVIGATIONS_LINKS, payload: data}));

    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private navigationService: NavigationService) {}
}
```

**Test File**

```
import { Http, Request, RequestOptionsArgs } from "@angular/http";
import { RouterModule, Router } from "@angular/router";


class HttpMock extends Http {

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): any {

    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): any {

    }
}

fdescribe('Tag Effect', () => {
    let runner: EffectsRunner;
    let navEffects: NavigationServiceEffect;
    let navService: NavigationService;
    let actions: Actions;

    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            EffectsTestingModule,
            RouterModule,
            StoreModule.provideStore(reducers())
        ],
        providers: [
            Actions,
            NavigationService,
            HttpService,
            { provide: Http, useClass: HttpMock },
            { provide: Router, useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate"); } }
        ]
    }));

    it('Call Load Navigation items action after Trigger Load aciton',
        inject([
            Actions, NavigationService
        ],
            ( _actions, _navService) => {
                actions = _actions;
                navService = _navService;

                spyOn(navService, 'load')
                    .and.returnValue(Observable.of([
                        { "name": "Help", "hasChild": false, "roles": [101, 151, 201, 301, 401], "url": "help" }
                    ]));


                navEffects = new NavigationServiceEffect(actions, navService);

                navEffects.navigations$.subscribe(r => console.log(r));

                navEffects.navigations$.subscribe(result => {

                    console.log(result);
                    expect(result.type).toEqual(NavigationActionType.LOAD_NAVIGATIONS_LINKS);
                    expect(result.payload.length).toEqual(3); // This should fail

                });
            }));

});
```

The test should fail as the length of the payload expected is 1 and is equal to 3 in the statement above so it should fail. But the test passes but no console output is logged. How can I test the above file?

Answer (score 1):

Your assertions are defined inside `subscribe`, which makes your test **asynchronous**.
In fact, your test is probably finishing before the action result is fired.
To fix this you need to wrap your test with `async` function like this:

```
   it('Call Load Navigation items action after Trigger Load aciton', 
      async(
        inject([
            Actions, NavigationService
        ],
            ( _actions, _navService) => {
                actions = _actions;
                navService = _navService;

                spyOn(navService, 'load')
                    .and.returnValue(Observable.of([
                        { "name": "Help", "hasChild": false, "roles": [101, 151, 201, 301, 401], "url": "help" }
                    ]));


                navEffects = new NavigationServiceEffect(actions, navService);

                navEffects.navigations$.subscribe(r => console.log(r));

                navEffects.navigations$.subscribe(result => {

                    console.log(result);
                    expect(result.type).toEqual(NavigationActionType.LOAD_NAVIGATIONS_LINKS);
                    expect(result.payload.length).toEqual(3); // This should fail

                });
            })));
```

More about `async` [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-async-function-in-it).